# The string I am searching for begins and ends with a wildcard character

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select only values that start and end with square brackets?

I have written

```
LIKE '[%]'
```

but it does not return anything. How can I work around this?

Comment: Yes but that did not pop up in my searches. This one is worded more directly

Comment: FYI, square brackets are not "wildcard characters".

Comment: They are according to w3 schools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets, because they are special characters in SQL Server `LIKE` patterns (square braces delineate character classes):

```
where col like '\[%\]'
```

If you don't like backslashes, you can use:

```
where col like '$[%$]' escape '$'
```

or not use `LIKE` at all:

```
where left(col, 1) = '[' and right(col, 1) = ']'
```

Comment: in your last query the first ] should be a '